# Volume flow rate

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble figuring out the second part of this problem. I found the rate at which the volume is increasing but I cannot figure out how to find the rate it is increasing at a specific radius when the volume flow rate is constant.

> If there is a constant volume flow rate entering a balloon ($4.78\times10^2$), how do you find the rate at which the radius is increasing at a specific radius?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the balloon here is to be thought of as a sphere. You are given that $\frac{dv}{dt} = 478$. The volume of a sphere is given by $v(r) = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$. If you know that radius is changing over time then $r$ is a function of $t$ and so by chain rule;

$$478  = \frac{dv}{dt} = 4\pi (r(t))^2  \cdot \frac{dr}{dt} \Rightarrow \frac{478}{4\pi (r(t))^2} = \frac{dr}{dt} = r'(t)$$

Comment: You've inverted things somewhere.  The units don't jive on the last equation.

Comment: @John Thanks. That was really stupid of me.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate the help and quick response!

Comment: Upvote @John, as I will as well. He pointed out a silly mistake that I made in the computation.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Hah thanks; just glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a spherical balloon:

$$V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3.$$

Take the time derivative of both sides:

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = 4 \pi r^2 \frac{dr}{dt}.$$

(The radius is also a function of $t$ so we use the chain rule to calculate the derivative.)

You know $dV/dt$.  If you know the radius at which you want to calculate $dr/dt$ (this is the case here) then just use the second equation directly.  If you know the volume, then solve for $r$ in the first equation beforehand.  Another interesting note is that $dV/dt$ is proportional to the surface area ($4\pi r^2$).